# how to resolve suspended Asynctask in android?

Tags: android, file, service, android-asynctask

I am working on asynctask. In that I am downloading file one after another.if one file downloaded then I call second file for download in Asynctask using service.It works fine but except file/Asynctask1 ,all other asynctask suspended and made 0kbps file in sdcard so,how can i resolve to downloading all files & execute all asynctask?

```
Synario:

Async1{

 downloading file1: it works fine & file downloaded

    oncomplete(){
        Async2();
    }
 }

Async2{

download file2:fail & file downloaded as 0kbps

   oncomplete(){
    Async3();
   }
}

Async3{

  downloading file3:fail & file downloaded as 0kbps

oncomplete(){
    exit;
}
}
```

Comment: why are not using a single `AsyncTask` to download all files.

Comment: i tried both the way,it download file 1 successdully after file2 & file3 downloaded as 0kbps mean it suspend file2 & file3 download.